# Android custom rounded progress view

Tags: android

I would like to build a custom progress audio player. like facebook do.

I use a csutom Linearview for this and GradientDrawables. I fill progress rect on Ondraw function.

```
public class wavPlayerView extends LinearLayout {

            private float mCornerRadius = 0;
            private float mProgressMargin = 0;
            private int progressColor;
            private boolean mFinish;

            private int mProgress=0;
            private int mMaxProgress = 100;
            private int mMinProgress = 0;

            private GradientDrawable mDrawableLayout;
            private GradientDrawable mDrawableProgressBackground;
            private GradientDrawable mDrawableProgress;
            private Context mContext;

            private wavPlayer mWavPlayer;


            private ImageView wavPlayerButton;
            private TextView wavPlayerDuration;


            public wavPlayerView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                initialize(context,null);
            }

            public wavPlayerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                initialize(context,attrs);
            }

            public wavPlayerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
                initialize(context,attrs);
            }

            /**
             *
             * @param context
             * @param attrs
             */
            private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                mContext=context;

                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.wav_player_layout, this);
                setOrientation(VERTICAL);

                //get elements
                wavPlayerButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wavPlayerBtn);
                wavPlayerDuration=(TextView)  findViewById(R.id.wavDuration);

                //Progress background drawable
                mDrawableProgressBackground = new GradientDrawable();
                //Progress drawable
                mDrawableProgress = new GradientDrawable();
                //Normal drawable
                mDrawableLayout = new GradientDrawable();

                //Get default normal color
                int defaultButtonColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wite);
                //Get default progress color
                int defaultProgressColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                //Get default progress background color
                int defaultBackColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);


                TypedArray attr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProgressLayout);
                try {
                    mProgressMargin = attr.getDimension(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_progressMargin, mProgressMargin);
                    mCornerRadius = attr.getDimension(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_cornerRadius, mCornerRadius);
                    //Get custom normal color
                    int layoutColor = attr.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_layoutColor, defaultButtonColor);
                    //Set normal color
                    mDrawableLayout.setColor(layoutColor);
                    //Get custom progress background color
                    int progressBackColor = attr.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_progressBackColor, defaultBackColor);
                    //Set progress background drawable color
                    mDrawableProgressBackground.setColor(progressBackColor);
                    //Get custom progress color
                    progressColor = attr.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_progressColor, defaultProgressColor);
                    //Set progress drawable color
                    mDrawableProgress.setColor(progressColor);

                    //Get default progress
                    mProgress = attr.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_progress, mProgress);
                    //Get minimum progress
                    mMinProgress = attr.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_minProgress, mMinProgress);
                    //Get maximize progress
                    mMaxProgress = attr.getInteger(R.styleable.ProgressLayout_maxProgress, mMaxProgress);

                } finally {
                    attr.recycle();
                }
                //Set corner radius
                mDrawableLayout.setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);
                mDrawableProgressBackground.setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);

                setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableLayout);

                mFinish = false;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

               if (mProgress > mMinProgress && mProgress <= mMaxProgress && !mFinish) {
                    //Calculate the width of progress
                    float progressWidth =
                            (float) getMeasuredWidth() * ((float) (mProgress - mMinProgress) / mMaxProgress - mMinProgress);

                    if(progressWidth >= (getMeasuredWidth()-mCornerRadius)){
                     mDrawableProgress.setCornerRadii(new float[]{mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius});
                    } else{
                     mDrawableProgress.setCornerRadii(new float[]{mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, 0, 0, 0, 0, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius});
                    }


                  //Set rect of progress
                   mDrawableProgress.setBounds(0,0,
                        (int) (progressWidth),(int)getMeasuredHeight());

                   //Draw progress
                   mDrawableProgress.draw(canvas);

                    if (mProgress == mMaxProgress) {
                        setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableLayout);
                        mFinish = true;
                    }
                }
                super.onDraw(canvas);
            }


            /**
             * Set current progress
             */
            public void setProgress(int progress) {
                if (!mFinish) {
                    mProgress = progress;
                    setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableProgressBackground);
                    invalidate();
                }
            }

            public void setMaxProgress(int maxProgress) {
                mMaxProgress = maxProgress;
            }

            public void setMinProgress(int minProgress) {
                mMinProgress = minProgress;
            }

            public void reset() {
                mFinish = false;
                mProgress = mMinProgress;

            }


            public wavPlayer getmWavPlayer() {
                return mWavPlayer;
            }        
         }
```

### problem

The problem is with the rounded corners of linearLayout. when i draw progress rect is out of the layout and became inside when it leave corners .

[image: screenchot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenchot4]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem using this mathematic formula :

[[image: figure]]

[[image: a=]]

this is the new code :

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

       if (mProgress > mMinProgress && mProgress <= mMaxProgress && !mFinish) {
            //Calculate the width of progress
            float progressWidth =
                    (float) getMeasuredWidth() * ((float) (mProgress - mMinProgress) / mMaxProgress - mMinProgress);

            if(progressWidth >= (getMeasuredWidth()-mCornerRadius)){
                float diff=progressWidth-((getMeasuredWidth()-mCornerRadius));
                mDrawableProgress.setBounds(0,0,
                        (int) (progressWidth),(int)getMeasuredHeight());
                mDrawableProgress.setCornerRadii(new float[]{mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius,diff,diff,diff, diff, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius});
                //Draw progress
                mDrawableProgress.draw(canvas);
            } else{

                if(progressWidth<mCornerRadius){

                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor(progressColor);
                    double a=2* Math.sqrt(progressWidth*((2*mCornerRadius)-progressWidth));
                    float rectTop=(float)(getMeasuredHeight()-a)/2;
                    RectF rect=new RectF(0,rectTop,2*progressWidth,(float)(rectTop+a));
                    canvas.drawArc(rect,90,180,true,paint);


                }else{
                    //Set rect of progress
                    mDrawableProgress.setBounds(0,0,
                            (int) (progressWidth),(int)getMeasuredHeight());
                    mDrawableProgress.setCornerRadii(new float[]{mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, 0, 0, 0, 0, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius});
                    //Draw progress
                    mDrawableProgress.draw(canvas);
                }

            }

            if (mProgress == mMaxProgress) {
              //  setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableLayout);
                mFinish = true;
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```

here the result :

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]